# Make subcategory as array in object of array

Tags: javascript, json, typescript, django-rest-framework

I'm working on django rest and angular. This json array is coming from server and contains category and subcategory values.
my code will create category and related subcategory in separate keys of array. But i want keep subcategory as a array in object in same object.

Result should be like this:

`[{"title":"title of category","sub":[array of related sub]} , ...]`

mycode:

```
  public data = SERVERRESPONE;
  public categories = [];

      this.data.filter(c => c.parent_id === null).map(c => <{ title: {}; subcategories: {} }>{
        title: {"title":c.title},
        subcategories: this.data.filter(sc => sc.parent_id === c.cat_id).map(sc => sc.title)
      }).forEach(c => {
        this.categories.push([c.title, [c.subcategories]]);
      });
```

server response :

```
[
        {
            "id": 5,
            "cat_id": 0,
            "parent_id": null,
            "title": "web development"
        },
        {
            "id": 6,
            "cat_id": 1,
            "parent_id": null,
            "title": "android development"
        },
        {
            "id": 7,
            "cat_id": null,
            "parent_id": 0,
            "title": "php"
        },
        {
            "id": 8,
            "cat_id": null,
            "parent_id": 1,
            "title": "java"
        }
    ]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it is nice question but it has very easy solution!

```js
const array = [
    {
        "id": 5,
        "cat_id": 0,
        "parent_id": null,
        "title": "web development"
    },
    {
        "id": 6,
        "cat_id": 1,
        "parent_id": null,
        "title": "android development"
    },
    {
        "id": 7,
        "cat_id": null,
        "parent_id": 0,
        "title": "php"
    },
    {
        "id": 8,
        "cat_id": null,
        "parent_id": 1,
        "title": "java"
    }
]

let result = []


for (let key of array) {

    if (key.parent_id === null) {
        let new_key = key,
            sub = []

        for (let iterator of array) 
            if (iterator.parent_id === key.cat_id)
                sub.push(iterator)

        new_key.sub = sub
        result.push(new_key)
    }

}

console.log(result)
```

Comment: What happen if it will go upto level 4